# Should I install ReSharper 4.5 beta, and using Beta VS plug-ins in general

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, resharper

I'm running ReSharper 4.1 and was wondering if anyone is using 4.5 beta? how stable is it, etc.

Also how do people feel about using beta VS plug-ins in general on work systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched to the 4.5 beta two days ago, and for me at least, their claims of less memory usage are valid. I actually had to request a new computer because things were slowing to a crawl, and it looks like it was ReSharper causing it. 2GB of RAM fully used and constantly swapping out to the page file.

Of course, our solution has 92 projects in it, so it's not entirely their fault, but the point is, the beta seems very stable to me, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I installed it a few days ago, I've had Visual Studio freeze and crash on me three times and each time the only thing that would show up is the message "Parsing Source Files" from ReSharper. I'm not sure if the problem is the solution or the plugin, but other than that it is very stable, and much faster than 4.1.

I actually prefer using beta's on my development system because unlike my home computer I actually take care to protect my work and back it up. Not much harm running a beta plugin can do that I can't undo immediately.

Comment: I'm just the opposite my home system is where I run a lot of beta stuff, everything I care about it backed up, if the systems gos down so what, at work I want to keep my systems as stable, nothing like the joy of explaining that your going to be late on something because of some tool you installed

Comment: I guess you're right. But I'm the newbie in my office, so using my system as the development 'guinea pig' isn't really a big deal around here :P

Answer (score 1):

i switched to beta and it has better performance than before.. you should try it.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using the ReSharper 4.5 beta here with no problems. There is a noticeable difference in load time with 4.5, much faster. I highly recommended updating.